# Scraper unable to extract titles from a website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with Selenium to extract the titles of different news being displayed in the left sided bar in finance.yahoo website. I've used css selector to get the content. However, the script is neither giving any result nor throwing any error. I can't figure out the mistake I'm making. Hope somebody will take a look into it. Thanks in advance.

Here is my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "u.StretchedBox")))
for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("u.StretchedBox span"):
    print(item.text)   
driver.quit()
```

Elements within which the titles are:

```
<h3 class="M(0)" data-reactid="128"><a rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" class="Fw(b) Fz(20px) Lh(23px) LineClamp(2,46px) Fz(17px)--sm1024 Lh(19px)--sm1024 LineClamp(2,38px)--sm1024 Td(n) C(#0078ff):h C(#000)" target="_blank" href="https://beap.gemini.yahoo.com/mbclk?bv=1.0.0&amp;es=bVwDtPMGIS8NDKqncZWZBjLsQQHm58Z9cLJuMqC6LadDlYfVCoy.d3GqO599EPAiYnsxB0SB8aRURPve9Q8mOEjH.NrcVcVDhldut.C_9Vn16XER1q1G07a48FMQ_.sv9GCyVx7zcj1kBtWPysaYzQqboJWgUo5DRRHbAnejwVtYRPHJTEptil92tx_ccJZ9FnxE8L3tfDuS0Q3l5ftVhamTOon_nzuvtvqqBwD7X0T.7Z3wZBgtH93gM1xImZ0hdFUzsuQPDAjZWs1KdH0YsXIf3uLrmcJFoI9leh8KRljnIPC.RdhOF6OYcJfHtDks85nSIgfOsMyUr1wEhMA2Qa2htpEg5w.P4UIXeoldjzJ_NsUrtXqEFIJNKoaeq_FNiQ9wcI16utKO87167zkfSPzVY09d3pVLZg20V7tqTThOkG_IakPnmlOriJKnufsBWj1wp.6Q4PasAt2g4Y1yw9U71FIfG2dDwpryRKDWrUBfTvjwwItlSyXyvWvIYUyXXxR74qWcIEC3KAvVN7.iqSckV_EssVM8ytp5HiN4iTACpEmc96rpdNEqHYpRotwze8NF5cDubsZbW58Hauq_aO.DbhZJ7TbBDx5vZK_M%26lp=https%3A%2F%2Fin.search.yahoo.com%2Fsearch%3Fp%3Dcheap%2Bairfare%2Bdomestic%26fr%3Dstrm-tts-thg%26.tsrc%3Dstrm-tts-thg%26type%3Dcheapairfaredomestic-in" data-reactid="129">


<u class="StretchedBox" data-reactid="130"></u>

<span data-reactid="131">The Cheapest Domestic Airfare Rates</span></a></h3>
```

Comment: i don't see any `span` inside `u` on the website. could you put a screenshot of the value you are interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't get neither error nor results because:

- `find_elements_...()` method intend to return you a `list`. If your selector match no elements you won't get error, just an empty list. Also if to try to iterate through the empty list, you won't get error
- your CSS selector should match `span` that is descendant of `u` with attribute `class="StretchedBox"`, but actually required `span` is not *descendant*, but *sibling*.

Try to use below code:

```
for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("u.StretchedBox+span"):
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your answer. Your answer never fails to amaze me. It does fetch the above title but not all the titles I'm after.

Comment: It seems that not all titles located inside `span` . Try to use `XPath` instead of CSS selector: `//a[u[@class="StretchedBox"]]`

Comment: Again, you left me dumbfounded sir. It does the trick. You always come up with something new. Could you please let me understand with a one liner explanation- why "u" tag within "square braces"? Thanks one again sir.

Comment: This `XPath` means that you want to match anchor tag (`a`) that contains underline tag (`a[u]`), that contains `class` attribute with appropriate value (`u[@class="StretchedBox"]`). This is common case when you want to get parent element matced by its children. For example, `//div/a/span` returns you `span` matched by ancestors, but `//div[a[span]]` returns you `div` matched by descendants

Comment: Now it's crystal. Gonna get it by heart. Thanks again sir.